# Can Firebase Store Arabic Data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner and want to implement an Android application. I decided to use Firebase so can I store Arabic Data using it ?

Comment: Not sure what's too broad about this. It's a short question, but not overly vague, and quite specific: Can Firebase store Arabic data or not? "Yes" or "No" doesn't seem particularly broad for an answer either and can easily be answered _in a paragraph or two_. Voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase stores strings as Unicode. So as long as you ensure it fits into a Unicode character set, you can store Arabic characters.

```
ref.setValue("أَبْجَدِي");
```

Comment: I store manually data in arabic firebase. but return wrong.